# Hold some collection in RAM in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one collection that is small but I have lots of readings from it and I have wondering can you say to mongodb to keep some collection in RAM (cash them) all the time?

I could take redis and put all stuff that I want to cash in it but since it is relatively complex structure (arrays etc) it would be really easier to work with mongodb queries and I don't have to worry about putting cash to disc and other things.

Tnx :)

Comment: Providing that your OS never overwrites or pages out the data in RAM then it is completely possible, you can also use the mongodb touch() command or a script to run the query pushing the data to RAM once every so often

Comment: aha..so there is no some "high level" order to say to mongo to do this touch() every time when OS moves data from memory....

Comment: I'm also curious about situation when for example i have 16 GB RAM free and mongodb data is 1 GB. Will all my data be in memory by default?

Comment: No, well hmm. I don't think so, it is possible for MongoDB to understand when something isn't in RAM but I do not believe it has any method by which to push something back into RAM automatically or to physically pin it. Provided your data is warm it should all be in RAM. There are times where a prolonged amount of inactivity (normally on Windows) can give way to the OS paging out the data but normally it should only page it out once the amount of allocated RAM is used up and more needs paging in.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a hot collection (not inactive and reading a lot from it) it will be on RAM. you only have to ensure you have enough RAM and that the table has lots of activity. You can also use touch when it doesn't.

Comment: mongodb touch command is available from version 2.2 on and is described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/). This [parse blog entry](http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/07/techniques-for-warming-up-mongodb/) has some suggestions for using vmtouch or dd.

Comment: Just want to add to the above comment now and say that I came across it and it sounded useful, but it doesn't work with WiredTiger storage. So almost useless now.